# Finding Elements inside of a jQuery Object

Tags: jquery

Let me start by saying im not 100% the way Im handling this is correct, but anyway..

I am loading HTML out of a file, into a string - and placing that string inside of a jquery object.

My HTML (example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
         ...
    <link href="template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>

     <img src="img.png"/> 

     ...

     </body>
</html>
```

The above is in a variable called htmlstr:

```
var htmlstr = theFunctionThatLoadsMyHTMLString();
$html = $(htmlstr);
```

Now, im going through the HTML and attempting to make some changes before I put it into an iframe.

This works perfectly fine for images:

```
 $html.find("img").each(function(){
      // do something
 });
```

But, when I try to access the LINK tag (to change the css href) it doesn't find "link".

```
 $html.find("link").each(function(){
      // do something
 });
```

To attempt to debug the problem, I wrote this code:

```
$html.find('*').each(function(index){
    addline(index+': '+this.tagName+'');
});
```

It prints out the HTML tag found for each element (addline is a function that does this). This is what I get:

```
0: IMG
1: DIV
2: DIV
....
```

So it appears as if maybe its starting inside BODY for some reason, and ignoring the header?

What am I doing wrong here?

Im not gonna lie, Im not 100% sure how the $('code here') works in jQuery.. flying kind of blind.

Comment: Can you try doing `.find('head')`?

Comment: @OhCaN - I tried that and it returns nothing. I think my Problem is I need to escape the HTML I am feeding into the object. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2). I a replace function I found `htmlstr.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g,'\\$1')`, and it found the head element, but in return also had me end up with bad HTML because it was all filled with `\\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a browser-specific effect here.  The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) say

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM
>   that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, we use
>   the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert
>   it into the current document. During this process, some browsers
>   filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>`
>   elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative
>   of the original string passed.

Comment: Im actually doing this inside Titanium Desktop, wich is a WebKit browser. Probably should have mentioned that... but for all relative purposes... we could say im using "Chrome".

Comment: Tho, that is very interesting. Could be part of my problem.

Comment: This was exactly my problem! I fixed it by renaming HEAD to DERP before processing, then renaming it back before display. This stopped the browser from stripping the head elements. Kind of a funny workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Reproduced the problem in a JSFiddle and found that you can actually select the link if you know its position in the array. So, given that is is a fixed HTML, you could use that to find the link. However, I couldn't use any selector to find it, which is weird...

http://jsfiddle.net/66UjW/

If you plan on using this, you should test it for crossbrowser issues, since all browser might not parse the head the same.

Comment: It should be mentioned that my html file is actually much larger then that, and it has to handle multiple html files (not all structured the same). I think the issue is probably with escaping.. Im just not sure the best way to escape before I insert. Im researching the problem more now.